# Proposed proof of continuous operator on Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Hi I am interested in a question about continuity: Assume that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded and consider operator $$f:W^{1,p}(\Omega) \times L^{p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n}) \rightarrow L^{q}(\Omega)$$ to be (weak $\times$ norm, norm) continuous. Does the following argument make sense:
If $u_{k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then it follows that $\nabla u \rightharpoonup \nabla u $ in $L^{p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Therefore $$f(u_{k},\nabla u_{k}) \rightharpoonup f(u,\nabla u)~~\text{in }L^{q}(\Omega)$$

Is this fine?

If this is not fine, can it at least be shown that $\{f(u_{k}, \nabla u_{k})\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded in $L^{q}(\Omega)$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is $c$ on your post?

Comment: It seems that $c=f$. Also, the conclusion appears to require $\nabla u_k\to \nabla u$ in the norm. You can get this convergence from Rellich-Kondrachov, provided that the theorem applies (e.g., the domain is bounded).

Comment: @Behaviour Yes that was a typo. But does it not follow also from the fact that (weak $\times$ norm, norm) continuity implies (weak $\times$ weak, weak) continuity for continuous operators? In the same way that (norm,norm) coninuity implies (weak, weak) continuity.

Comment: @wisher It was a typo. I corrected it, was supposed to be $f$. If we assume that $u_{k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Then using the continuity of $f$ does it follow then that $\{f(x,u_{k}(x), \nabla u_{k}(x))\}_{k}$ is bounded. The reasoning being that since $f$ is continuous it is also bounded, so it takes bounded sets to bounded sets. Is this fine?

Comment: @Behaviour I don't see how you would you use Rellich Kondrachov to get $\nabla u_{k} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^{p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n})$? Given that I am using this statement of [the theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theoremv)?